python deepdiff include_paths different result caused by not included paths
I want to compare some paths of two dicts with deepdiff. But depending on the presence or absence of other "not included" paths, deepdiff gives different results.
What is causing this behavior here?
from deepdiff import DeepDiff

DeepDiff(
    {
        'name': 'Testname',
        'code': 'bla',
        'noneCode': 'blu',
    }, {
        'uid': '12345',
        'name': 'Testname',
    },
    include_paths = "root['name']"
) # expected to be {}, but detects a change

DeepDiff(
    {
        'name': 'Testname',
        'code': 'bla',
    }, {
        'uid': '12345',
        'name': 'Testname',
    },
    include_paths = "root['name']"
) # expected to be {} and is {}


I suppose you are referring to this library.

Yes, thanks! I also added the import statement to the code snippet, so that it is clear.

It is a bug in DeepDiff described and fixed here https://github.com/seperman/deepdiff/issues/493
